# Angular PrimeNG menubar: Hide default down arrows next to menu titles

Tags: css, angular, primeng

The default PrimeNG menubar includes a little down arrow next to every main menu title. I want to remove the down arrows completely from the top-level menu title. Nested sub-menus may display a right arrow to show there is a sub-menu, and those can stay. Here are some screenshots with default menubar:

[image: PrimeNG Menubar Arrows]

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar

I can change the icons in the menu items easily, but can't find a handle to change/hide the arrows.

I'm using Angular CLI 9.1.8 and PrimeNG 9.1.0.

Comment: Could you please provide a StackBlitz with default PrimeNG configuration?

Comment: I tried setting this up in stackblitz, but ngcc compiler fails with error "ngcc failed to run on primeng@9.1.0". I'll keep trying to fix that and will post an update if I get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to hide it in style.css change its content like

```
.pi-caret-down::before{
   content: "";
}
```

check in developer console inspect element font name then make its before css as `content: "";`

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:none` has the added benefit of resizing the `menuitem` container to adjust for the removed arrow icon. Otherwise, you will be left with a blank space.

```css
.pi-caret-down {
   display:none;
}
```